# Why user becomes nobody?

Tags: linux, nfs, ownership, user-management

I have a problem about linux user,
I use a command to add user like:

```
useradd -u 532 -d /data/test01 -g test test01
```

but when I login as `test01` and run `mkdir x`,
it becomes like:

> nobody test  x

Why user becomes `nobody`?
How do I fix it ?

Comment: Perhaps better at Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: or superuser if it's not ubuntu. [note to admin : those 2 comments predate the migration and could be deleted]

Comment: Could you provide the output of `grep 532 /etc/passwd`?

Comment: test01:x:532:528::/data/test01:/bin/bash

Comment: If you do `ls -ldn x` do you get `532 528 x` for your directory ownership? And what about `grep nobody /etc/passwd`?

Comment: yeah,the file owner uid is 99 not 532 , but I use chown test01:test x , it would be nobody again , so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin

Comment: What are the complete permissions of the parent directory of `x`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. 2 nobody test 6 Mar 13 17:04 x

Comment: by the way , my server is using nfs , but I add user at all server by  same uid everytime.

Comment: Try doing: `touch /tmp/test01; ls -l /tmp/test01` is the output is correct then see @glglgl answer, it is more than probably your NFS configuration on this box that should be investigated.

Comment: My nfs server is OK , it doesn't have nobody problem,But others nfs client has. What can I do?

Comment: @Rosser OK, I provided you with an alternative explanation + solution in my existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible explanation is that you run this stuff on a filesystem which is fixed to one user.

Cases for this could be `ntfs` or `vfat`.

A `nfs` mount with `root_squash` (the default) might be another reason.

Answer (score 0):

### User alias

A possible explanation is that you already had a user called nobody with the UID (User ID) 532. The result is you have created a "user alias".

You either can try to specify another UID for your user (or let the system pick-up one). Or you can leave it like that. The only security risk is that if a service or other user can access `nobody`'s data then it will be able to access your data.

### NFS User ID Mapping

For users to have the feeling they are accessing their own files, the UID on the NFS server should match the UID on the NFS clients. Although, you want to avoid that for `root` at least.

By default, NFS exportfs will choose UID/GID of 65534 which corresponds to your user `nobody`'s UID. You need to instruct the NFS server not to map all UID to 65534 or if this is the wanted behaviour, you need to specify the mapped default UID.

For the first case, remove the `all_squash` and replace it by `root_squash`, but bare in mind that any non root user with a similar UID between the NFS server and any clients will be a match, so they own the files"

For the second case, keep the `all_squash` but add `anonuid=532` (you can use also `anongid` for the GID (or Group ID)).

Example:

```
/               pc001(rw,root_squash)
/home/joe       pc002(rw,all_squash,anonuid=532,anongid=100)
```

Note: the changes should be done in the file `/etc/exports` on the NFS server.

Comment: my nobody uid is 99 : nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin

Comment: Thank for your explanation + solution , but the /etc/passwd in my NFS server is the same form NFS client , and my NFS server set is like : (rw,no_root_squash,sync), it should use the same uid not nobody...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **usermod** command to modify various user parametes like the *username* and the *UID*.